# What do we call linear maps from the base field to a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

This is just a terminological question for some notes I'm writing: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. A linear map $T:V\to F$ is called a *linear functional*.

What do we call a linear map $v\colon F\to V$? I'm inclined to call them cofunctionals, but I don't think this is standard.

[Linear functionals are also called "covectors". So maybe "cocovectors"? Then the natural identification $L(F,V)\cong V$ ($v\mapsto v(1)$) would identify vectors and cocovectors, which is nice.]

---

**Edit**: Just for motivation, these maps $F\to V$ are helpful for writing down general linear maps in terms of functionals and 'cofunctionals' (which are easy to deal with), and apply that to study ideals of linear operators, for example.

If $T:V\to V$ is linear with $dim(V)<\infty$, then $T=\sum_k (Tp_k)q_k=\sum_k p_k(q_kT)$, where the $q_k$ are a basis for $V^*$ (dual of $V$) and the $p_k$ are right-inverses of the $q_k$.

The $q_k$ and $q_kT$ are functionals, and $p_k$ and $Tp_k$ are 'cofunctionals'.

Comment: The image of such a map will either be trivial or a one-dimensional subspace, so they are not particularly interesting, which may or may not be a reason for why they don't have a name.

Comment: As you say, they can canonically be identified with just elements of $V$, so there's no need for a separate name for them.

Comment: They're just called "vectors."

Comment: If we want to distinguish it from 'vector', I'd suggest the name '(parametric) line' or 'parametric one dimensional subspace'

Comment: The term "cocovector," if you want to use it at all, should IMO be reserved for an element of the double dual space $(V^{\ast})^{\ast}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a canonical identification $\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb F,V)\cong V$ for any $\Bbb F$-vector space $V$. (Here $\operatorname{Hom}$ is the set of $\Bbb F$-linear maps from $\Bbb F$ to $V$.) The map is exactly as you describe and takes $f$ to $f(1)$.

So in my opinion, it would make sense to say linear maps $f\colon V\to \Bbb F$ are covectors and maps $g\colon \Bbb F\to V$ are vectors. However, there is not much to be gained here. It would just cause confusion, as we already think of vectors as elements in the underlying set $V$.

One thought I just had: this is only tangentially related, but one way to define the tangent space of a point $p$ in a smooth manifold $M$ is by equivalence classes of curves $\gamma\colon \Bbb R\to M$ (or $\gamma\colon(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ for any $\varepsilon>0$). The point is that a $\gamma$ represents the tangent vector $\gamma'(0)$ in the tangent space of $\gamma(0)$. It is not entirely coincidental here that we basically identify maps $f\colon\Bbb R\to M$ with certain vectors. (Dually, a map $g\colon M\to \Bbb R$ defines a covector at each point.)

Comment: The last comment makes sense. If we take $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a manifold, then the tangent space at whatever point is $\mathbb{R}^n$ again. We are just representing a vector $v$ of this tangent space by the linear map $\gamma:t\mapsto tv$, as you mentioned we do for manifolds.